# Import-Package/Export-Package for creating bundle for ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I want to create a bundle which uses hibernate for database transactions. I was using plain `sql` before moving to hibernate. After mentioning hibernate and related config in `camel.xml`, I tried to deploy the bundle in ServiceMix. When I tried to start this bundle using `start 525`, I got an error message saying:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
    Error starting bundle 525: Unable to resolve my.package.artifactid [525](R 525.0): missing requirement [my.package.artifactid [525](R 525.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.interceptor) Unresolved requirements: [[my.package.artifactid [525](R 525.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.interceptor)]
```

This is for javax.interceptor. I put this package in `<Export-Package></Export-Package>` in the maven bundle felix plugin in `pom.xml`. This resolved the issue but later showed the same error for org.hibernate and other packages. 
My question is, did I do it right when I put it in `<Export-Package>` tag? If this is right, I have to keep doing this for a large number of packages. Is there a way to get rid of this hectic procedure?
If I did it wrong, what should I have done?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that your module needs to import javax.inteceptor. Can you try putting "javax.interceptor" into <Import-Package> instead? Regarding imports: you can leave it up to the maven bundle plugin to fill most of the <Import-Package> manifest entry by specifying <Import-Package>*</Import-Package> in the configuration of maven bundle plugin. If maven bundle plugin misses some of the required packages, add them after the asterisk: <Import-Package>*, package1, package2</Import-Package>

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have done wrong.

> ```
> missing requirement [my.package.artifactid [525](R 525.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.interceptor)
> ```

The error states that, the package javax.interceptor is required by your bundle (Ex. the classes in your bundle makes use of classes in package javax.interceptor either directly by referencing them or indirectly through use of any framework like hibernate) and without which your bundle is not able to load the referenced classes.

Now, follow the below steps to get this resolved.

1. In pom.xml, under maven-bundle-plugin, do not specify explicit import-
   package list. Remove the tag if you specified. This will make sure the 
   bundle plugin calculates the dependencies on his own.
2. Build the bundle. Check the *generated* manifest.mf file of your bundle. The import-package: header must have the entry for package javax.interceptor.
3. Now, you need to ensure that javax.interceptor package is exported by atleast one bundle in servicemix.(Check [these commands](https://servicemix.apache.org/docs/7.x/users-guide/using-console.html) & [use webconsole](https://servicemix.apache.org/docs/7.x/users-guide/web-console.html) to know a bundle that exports this package.
4. If you do not find any bundle that exports this package, you need to add such bundle.
5. You can use google to find if any library that export this package like [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.interceptor/javax.interceptor-api/1.2-b06). Make sure, the jar is a bundle and not a plain jar.
6. Most of the time, the transitive dependencies in maven if deployed to servicemix as is, will do the job.
7. It could happen that, if you deploy a jar that exports javax.interceptor, the deployed jar may be depend on some other jar. So, make sure the deployed jars status appear as Started in Servicemix.